# What does "to confuse the Satan" mean and why does it work?

Tags: minhag, hashkafah-philosophy, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, shofar, satan

There are several things we don't do in order "to confuse the Satan", [like not blowing Shofar on Erev Rosh Hashana](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14327&st=&pgnum=303). How does it help? Does Satan not realize that Rosh Hashana 
didn't pass yet? He doesn't see our calendars?

Comment: I know that there is another reason given, that is to make a pause between blowing as a minhag and blowing as a din. Yet this reason is also given. What does it mean?

Comment: I remember hearing a shiur from R' Yossi Jacobson on a sicha about this. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: The Meiri says this is why we blow Motizeh Yom Kippur too.

Comment: Do you want to extend this question to also mention the practice of blowing 100 blasts on RH itself to "confuse the Satan"? See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22578693#22578693

Comment: Does "it does not help" qualify as a an answer?

Comment: @mevaqesh not really. It's a good answer if I didn't provide a source and you found a source that it doesn't help. But the Magen Avraham quotes it, so there *has* to be something there

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Were sources to state that contrary to the gemara and magen avraham it does not help, would that suffice? Something along the lines of the Meiri cited [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351).

Comment: חידושי הרשב"א מסכת ראש השנה דף טז עמוד ב 
ופי' כדי לערבב את השטן. יש מפרשים להכניע היצר כדכתיב אם יתקע שופר בעיר ועם לא יחרדו ושטן הוא יצר הרע וכדר"ל דאמר (ב"ב ט"ז א') הוא שטן היא יצר הרע היא מלאך המות . This relatively rationalistic explanation would seem to preclude the understanding that the question is predicated on. Unless one twists the Rashba like a pretzel.

Comment: בית הבחירה למאירי מסכת ראש השנה דף טז עמוד א 
כדי לערבב את השטן המסית והמדיח בהתמדת המצוה. The Meiri adds the words בהתמדת המצוה to explain that the accomplishment is based on extra mitzvot. Accordingly, the Meiri's explanation precludes the assumption of the question.

Comment: Rashi also sounds like the Meiri: 
כדי לערבב - שלא ישטין, כשישמע ישראל מחבבין את המצוות - מסתתמין דבריו. As does the Riaz there. This is also the implication of the Ittur.

Comment: R' Asher MiLunel also seems to go like rashi. incidentally the explanation cited by the rashba is found in the malmad hatalmidim: ספר מלמד התלמידים פרשת נצבים 
אמר שכונתם היתה לערבב השטן וידוע שהשטן הוא יצר הרע כמו שבא מפורש בדברי חכמים כפי מה שקדם בפרשת בהעלותך. נמצא שהוספת התקיעות מתוך הברכות והתפלה באה להשלים הכונה במצוה לגעור ביצר הרע המעכב התשובה ולערבב אותו שאין במקום התקיעה שטן נמצא אחר שיתערבב.

Comment: To summarize, according to rashi, meiri, baal haittur, riaz, r' asher milunel, and others the question is based on a false premise.

Comment: Let's say for a moment we do mess him up. Comes around the next year and we employ *exactly the same tactic.* Even if we can fool him for a few years, we've been doing this for at least 2000+ years. You don't think he's caught on by now? And again, this is the Satan. He's been able to get so many to sin over the millennia. He's a pretty smart guy - it shouldn't take much for him to catch on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe said a sicha on this topic, and I really recommend reading it in full.
Abridged and translated [here](http://www.sichos-in-english.org/books/chassidic-dimension-festivals-1/04.htm).
Original and unedited [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=4620&st=%u05e9%u05d8%u05df).
Worked-up version by the Rebbe [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14947&st=&pgnum=238).

In summary,

> Rashi explains the concept of "confounding Satan" as follows: "So that he will not accuse; for when he hears how the Jewish people love the mitzvos, his words of accusation are stifled."

Essentially, our blowing shofar in different ways (sitting, standing, tekieah, shevarim, etc..), shows our love for the mitzvos and this causes the words of Satan to be suppressed.

We are not trying to confuse Satan about the *calendrical day* of Rosh Hashana, but-

> rather, it means that Satan won't know when the specific aspect of the period of judgment of Rosh HaShanah comes about - the point of time when he presents his accusations. This is stated explicitly in the Maharil:[23] "He does not know when is the time of judgment; when he is to come and accuse."
>
> When a Jew repents properly prior to the onset of Rosh HaShanah, then he is already assured that he will be written and sealed in the Book of the Righteous. In other words, by repenting prior to Rosh HaShanah, his judgment for the good was already assured during the month of Elul.

So Satan sees his efforts are useless; we stopped blowing shofar even *before* Rosh Hashana, because we have already been forgiven, and this *confounds* his presentation in the Heavenly Court, because he sees that "כבר עבר ר״ה" - "Rosh Hashana already occurred". Not the *day* of Rosh Hashana, but the *judgement* of Rosh Hashana.

I would assume that the other minhagim that "confuse" Satan, are of the same sort - showing our confidence that we have already been written and sealed for a good, sweet year, filled with all good things.

Comment: what does that have to do with not blowing the shofar on the day before Rosh Hashana though?

Comment: @tomsmith The translated/edited sicha didn't really explain it, but the original did. Not the greatest editing job. I've edited my answer to include the part about not blowing shofar the day before.

Answer (score 13):

It is said in the name of Rabbi Akiva Eiger as follows:

The Talmud states that if one repents due to fear of punishment, his sins are converted to unintentional sins. However, if one repents out of love, his sins are converted to Mitzvoth (good deeds).

Rashi states that the extra shofar blasts show the love Jews have for Mitzvoth, this implies that their repentance is motivated by love rather than fear. Accordingly, their sins would be converted to Mitzvoth.

Satan is thus in a quandary: for every sin he brings up against the Jews, is subject to possible conversion to a good deed, which moves Hashem to shower blessing upon the Jews, the opposite of Satan's goal. When he hears the shofar blasts he gets confused and doesn't know how to proceed.

Comment: @tomsmith: One of the things we do to confound the Satan is an extra 30 shofar blasts at the end of the service.

Answer (score 7):

I remember reading a drasha by [Rabbi Chaim Smulevitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Shmulevitz) who gave an answer why we blow the shofar multiple times on Rosh Hashanah.

He said at the first blast the Satan prepares his arguments for the Day of Judgement. When he hears the second blast he assumes that Moshiach has now come and this agitates him so much he cannot deliver his accusations.

Is the Satan so foolish he is tricked every year with the same trick? Rabbi Shmulevitz says that the Satan is far more aware than we are of how close Moshiach is to coming. The teshuvah that the Jewish People need to do to bring Moshiach is something intimately close to them and requires in essence just a change of thinking. Knowing that, the Satan expects the Shofar HaGadol to blow at any moment.

Answer (score 3):

Nachum Klafter recently posted an [essay on Torah Musings](http://torahmusings.com/2013/09/confusing-satan/) proposing an answer to this question.

Read the whole thing, but in summary:
He suggests that the Satan here is our own evil inclination, and in particular, our unfortunate tendency to strip meaningful practices of their meaning by practicing them in a rote manner. As we've been blowing shofar for a whole month, we may naturally tend to adopt an automatic feeling toward the shofar blowing and the repentance it's supposed to inspire. We break the routine before the big event to vanquish this particular evil inclination and instead concentrate properly on the shofar and its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

"Judaism does not view the word “Satan” with the same connotation as other religions. Satan in Judaism is not a physical being, ruling the underworld or hell. Rather, in the Torah, the word Satan indicates “accuser,” “hinderer,” or “tempter.” Satan is more an obstacle in one’s way, such as temptation and evil doings, keeping them from completing the responsibilities of tikkun olam (fixing the world). Satan is our evil inclination to veer off the path of righteousness and faithfulness in G-d.

The Shofar is a wake-up call, a remind er that one wil hear and do all that HaShem commanded. So this could confuse or shaken up our yetzer hara and the drives that keeping us from this goal in order to get us back focused on the right track.

Comment: How does this answer the question?