# Source for Raincoat under Chuppah

Tags: minhag, clothing, wedding

There is a minhag among some people in recent years to wear a raincoat under the Chuppah. What is the source of this minhag? When did this minhag start? And is there anyone who specifically says not to do it?

Comment: I've heard about wearing a winter coat, since in Europe weddings were outdoors and it was often very cold.

Comment: @Ypnypn Have you heard of anyone doing that in warmer contexts?

Comment: IshPloniViKohen, adding evidence for such a minhag to the question will improve its value.

Comment: DoubleAA Yes; I've seen someone writing about wearing one indoors.

Comment: In Chabad, kallahs also wear a coat under the chuppah, regardless of the season. I'm not sure why.

Comment: The reason for a raincoat, specifically, is that it’s a coat that’s not warm. No need to roast the Chassan.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen people wearing a coat over a kittel at an indoor wedding. When I asked, I was told that it is a matter of modesty. The chosson is not claiming an 'exalted' status that might be implied by wearing the kittel. I was not given a source for this.

Comment: _Nit'e Gavriel_ cites a reason for a _chasan_ to wear his _kapote_ (or _bekeshe_ or whatever) over his _kitl_ as opposed to only his _kitl_. I think it may have been something like this, but don't recall for sure now. But he wasn't writing about a coat.

Comment: @msh210 Since these were 'yeshivish' weddings and they were bocherim, they would not have been wearing a kapote or bekeshe. I would guess that is why they wore raincoats.

Comment: Not _bachurim_ for long. `:-)`

Comment: @sabbahillel - In Chabad, the kapote is worn first at the chuppah. In other Hasidic groups, a bekishe is worn even by young children.

Answer (score 2):

I was told the coats are worn (by both chosson and kallah, in Chabad) to confuse the yetzer hara about the identity of the couple. (I have no idea if this is the real reason.)

Comment: +1 for the funniest answer I've read this week. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10213/501

Comment: @DannySchoemann Yeah. If we believe the yetzer hara exists, we seem to think he is an idiot